# Automatically scroll table when the selected row is the row before last row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have an issue related to scrolling table.
[image]

When the page is loaded, the first row (ROW 1) will be default selected row (highlighted row). If we click next button the next row will be selected and highlighted. The issue is if the ROW >= 8 (e.g ROW 9, 10...) being selected, the table do not automatically scroll so we can not see the current selected is also being highlighted.
Behaviours should be as follow  image:
[image]

When the ROW 8 is being selected, the table should be scrolled automatically. At this time, the next row (ROW 9) is VISIBLE and the top rows should be invisible.

My purpose is at current selected row I also can see the next row. The table should be scrolled when I click next/previous button until reach the last visible row and then that row will become the row before the last row.

I don't have any idea to solve this issue.
Please help me.

Best Regards,
Ken.

Comment: there is no verifiable example provided but you could utilize `$anchorScroll` to achieve this maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below snippet makes use of window to scroll to specific `tr` of the `table`.

On each next/prev click increment/decrease the `selectedIndex` respectively and scroll to that index of row in table.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
  $scope.rows = ["Row1", "Row2", "Row3", "Row4", "Row5", "Row6", "Row7", "Row8", "Row9", "Row10", "Row11", "Row12", "Row13", "Row14", "Row15", "Row16", "Row17", "Row18"];

  $scope.NextRow = function() {
    $scope.selectedIndex = $scope.selectedIndex === $scope.rows.length - 1 ? $scope.rows.length - 1 : $scope.selectedIndex + 1;
    var w = $(window);
    var row = $('table').find('tr').eq($scope.selectedIndex);
    if (row.length) {
      w.scrollTop(row.offset().top - (w.height() / 2));
    }
  }

  $scope.PrevRow = function() {
    $scope.selectedIndex = $scope.selectedIndex === 0 ? 0 : $scope.selectedIndex - 1;;
    var w = $(window);
    var row = $('table').find('tr').eq($scope.selectedIndex);

    if (row.length) {
      w.scrollTop(row.offset().top - (w.height() / 2));
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.anchor {
  border: 2px dashed DarkOrchid;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.fixed-header {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.fixed-header>a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <div class="fixed-header">
    <button ng-click="PrevRow()">Previous button </button>
    <button href="" ng-click="NextRow()">Next button </button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
          <td class="anchor" ng-style="selectedIndex == $index && {'background-color':'lightblue'}">{{row}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I havea similar issue, except that the scrollable element in my project is a div, not the window. The table is inside a div. When I use the above code (replacing $(window) with $('#myDiv') it does not work 100%. The selected row manages to scroll out of view after I move the selected row lower and lower in the table.